# Converting a table into relational tables

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

In my MySQL table I have a simple postal codes table that I have converted it from an .xlsx file.

```
Country   |City    |MiniDistrict |Postal Code
---------------------------------------------
Bulgaria  |Sofia   |Oborishte    | 0844
Bulgaria  |Sofia   |Sredets      | 0988
Bulgaria  |Plovdiv |Montana      | 1299
Bulgaria  |Plovdiv |Dyavol       | 1288
Bulgaria  |Varna   |Andeevo      | 1574
France    |Paris   |Mantois      |38992
France    |Paris   |Valois       |38764
France    |Gard    |Lussan       |55980
```

As you can see Country and city names are repeating numerious times. also note that there are same city names in different countries. I want to write a PHP algorithm where I'll generate a **country table**, a **city table**, and a **minidistrict-postalcode table** into MySQL. The country table is easy, `SELECT DISTINCT`. What algorythm should I write for the other tables? The algorytm idea will be enough for me, no need for the coding part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "algorithm" is this: you notice that every MiniDistrict has a PostalCode, and every PostalCode has its MiniDistrict. So you put these together in a single table, and associate each pair with an unique ID.

```
CREATE TABLE district_postalcode
(
    id integer not null primary key auto_increment,
    minidistrict varchar(???),
    postalcode char(5)
);
```

Then you notice that each city is a single object, and the same for the countries, so you create two tables for them, each with its own ID.

Now you must store a relationship between minidistricts and cities. But this is a many-to-one relationship: many minidistricts may belong to the same city, but the same minidistrict can't belong to two cities.

So you add a reference to `cities.id` as foreign key `city_id` to minidistricts.

The relationship structure is the same between cities and countries. So again you add a foreign key, this time `country_id` to `countries.id` into `cities`.

At that point, you can also create a `VIEW` to see your data as before:

```
CREATE VIEW old_style AS SELECT
    countries.Country,
    cities.City,
    districts.MiniDistrict,
    districts.PostalCode
FROM districts
    JOIN cities ON (cities.id = districts.city_id)
    JOIN countries ON (country.id = cities.country_id);
```

You can also populate your new `districts`, `cities` and `countries` from your existing data, beginning with the table that has no foreign keys:

```
INSERT INTO countries ( Country ) SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM old_table;

INSERT INTO cities ( City, country_id )
    SELECT DISTINCT City, Country.id
    FROM old_table
    JOIN countries ON ( old_table.Country = countries.Country );
```

(This will insert twice a city if it exists with the same name in two countries - one with each country ID - but that's as it should be: city names are normally not unique).

Answer (score 2):

try something like

table_Country

```
Country_id | country_name
  1        |   Bulgaria  
  2        |   France
```

table_City

```
City_id | Country_id | City_name 
   1    |  1         |   Sofia   
   2    |  1         |   Plovdiv 
   3    |  1         |   Andeevo   
   4    |  2         |   Paris   
   5    |  3         |   Gard
```

table_MiniDistrict

```
MiniDistrict_id | City_id | MiniDistrict_Postal
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need PHP to populate your new tables.

Here is an example :

1. Create tables with auto increment id and a name field
2. Populate tables using

   INSERT INTO country_name (name) (SELECT DISTINCT country FROM your_current_table)